# Bootstrap User Input in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up my page with the help of bootstrap.
Visit: [hubb.tekkkz.com](http://hubb.tekkkz.com)
I have the problem that if you click on login/register on the right, the modal appears. BUT! the user input elements aren't as wide as the parent container is, so the free space to the left between element and modal is lower than at the right side.

How to make the elements have the full container/parents width?

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" value=""></p>
                    <p><input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" value=""></p>
                    <p><input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Login"></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: yes right.. @Martin you should provide relevant code in question

Comment: What a code should i add? the bootstrap css? an it's bootstrap, there you cant add code, so remove the downrank or i report you!

Comment: better? i hope so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below css

```
#loginModal .form-inline .form-control, 
#registerModal .form-inline .form-control {
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Works at login, but register is failed now. Why?

Comment: do not use `container` class inside that modal, it cause to set the width to more than 1000px

Comment: thanks, works, now everything is correct. Btw, to make the button also the full-width i just need to append the form-control class to the button, right?
and it is not necessary to have teh class form-inline at the form when the elements shouldn't be in a line, right?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class add this class to the modelinputs

```
.form-control-login { 
width: 100% !important;  
}
```